# ASP.NET Entity Framework return JSON object of all rows inside table

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am trying to return JSON object from PostgreSQL db and currently saving to database works fine, but trying to return result returns nothing this is currently what I have for returning list from db. Keep in mind connection string is fine functionality for creating object to db works fine.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<TutorialMake>> ReadTutorialMake()
    {
        try
        {
            using (var db = new TutorialContext())
            {
                response = HttpStatusCode.OK;   

                return db.TutorialMakes.ToList();
            }
        } catch
        {
            response = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I've tried with returning only db.TutorialMakes without enumerable still nothings, removing try and catch returns no errors, iqueryable returns nothing and there is data inside table

Comment: you need to show your TutorialContext to get a full overview

Comment: I've started debugging and return has all the content in it it does contain whole list, but why is not getting to me back as JSON? There is object called results view that contains whole list, is there syntax to return it or is it displayed like that for debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Code is fine, it was just the way I configured my API I didn't return the list in API.

Answer (score 0):

Because you forget to convert `List` result to `JsonObject`

Example :

```cs
public async Task<JsonResult> ReadTutorialMake()
{
        try
        {
            using (var db = new TutorialContext())
            {
                response = HttpStatusCode.OK;   

                return Json(db.TutorialMakes.ToList()); //Convert result to JsonResult
            }
        } catch
        {
            response = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
            return null;
        }
}
```